# Solve $y''+(y')^2+1=0$ as a separable D.E.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the equation $y''+(y')^2+1=0$ .

I came across this problem in an old textbook of mine under the section of Separable Differential Equations. I am just not seeing how to do it! I'm not looking for the answer, just a little push in the right direction to get me started.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

The obvious substitution $z = y'$ gives $z' + z^2 + 1 = 0$ aka: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x} = -(1+z^2) \implies \int \frac{1}{1+z^2} \, \mathrm{d}z = \mathrm{C}-x$$

And so $\arctan y' = \mathrm{C}-x$ giving $y' = \tan (C-x)$

Then integrating $\int \tan (\mathrm{C}-x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ is a standard integral of $\int \tan x \, \mathrm{d}x = \ln |\sec x| + \mathrm{D}$ with a $x \mapsto C-x$ sub.

Answer (score 2):

substitute ${ y }^{ \prime  }=z\left( x \right) $(as suggested Ahmed Hussein ),then solve it respect to the $z$,so that $$y''+(y')^{ 2 }+1=0\\ { z }^{ \prime  }+{ z }^{ 2 }+1=0\\ \\ \frac { dz }{ dx } =-\left( { z }^{ 2 }+1 \right) \\ \int { \frac { dz }{ { z }^{ 2 }+1 }  } =-\int { dx } \\ \arctan { z } =-x+C\\ z=\tan { \left( -x+C \right)  } \\ \frac { dy }{ dx } =\tan { \left( -x+C \right)  } $$

$$\int { dy=\int { \tan { \left( -x+C \right)  } dx=\int { \frac { \sin { \left( -x+C \right)  }  }{ \cos { \left( -x+C \right)  }  } dx } =\int { \frac { d\cos { \left( -x+C \right)  }  }{ \cos { \left( -x+C \right)  }  }  }  } =\ln { C\left| \cos { \left( -x+C \right)  }  \right|  }  } \\$$

> $$ y=\ln { C\left| \cos { \left( -x+C \right)  }  \right|  } $$